# how to pass grid view data to the other view as per selected id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

```
//this is my web grid

using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="content">
        @grid.GetHtml(
          tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
          headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
          footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",//properties
          alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",//this are the 
          rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
          columns: grid.Columns(
              grid.Column(header: "job_id", format: @<text><div>@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1)</div></text>),
              grid.Column(columnName: "location", header: "location"),
              grid.Column(columnName: "jobtitle", header: "jobtitle"),
              grid.Column(columnName: "technology", header: "technology"),
              grid.Column(columnName: "job_description", header: "job_description"),
              grid.Column(columnName: "category", header: "category"),
              //this is link for navigating to next page with selected id                                                 
              grid.Column(columnName: "Apply",format:@<text>@Html.ActionLink("Apply", "JobDetails", "Client")</text>)
         ))
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then this may help:

Extract the grid component to a partial view and then it can be reused any where.

If you mean by extracting data only, then you have to use jQuery ajax to pick up data of interest.